# How do I display the Django '__all__' form errors in the template?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following form code:

```
# forms.py
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    hello = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    world = forms.CharField(max_length=40)

    def clean(self):
        raise forms.ValidationError('Something went wrong')

# views.py
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass
    else:
        form = SomeForm()

    data = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render_to_response(
        'someform.html',
        data,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )

# someform.html
{{ form.hello }}
{{ form.hello.errors }}

{{ form.world }}
{{ form.world.errors }}
```

How can I display the errors from the key `__all__` at the template level without having to  extract it in the view separately?  I want to avoid the following:

```
    if form.errors.has_key('__all__'):
        print form.errors['__all__']
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

Answer (score 41):

`{{ form.non_field_errors }}` for errors related to form not field

`{{ form.password.errors }}` for errors related to text-field like passoword in this case