# Django form validation using Ajax and multiple submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, submit

So far I have succeeded in implementing this view using dajax, but I find it very messy and as I've been reading so far it is good practice to have your view, well, in the view.py file.
I've tried implementing it using this guide: http://www.micahcarrick.com/ajax-form-submission-django.html but without being able to read which button is clicked.

The same view shall still be shown after submitting (no redirection) as the page also contains plotting and other statuses of my connected instruments.

models.py

```
class ActiveMeas(models.Model):
    channels    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    technology  = models.ForeignKey(TechnologyModel)
    samples     = models.IntegerField()
    delay       = models.IntegerField()
    table       = models.IntegerField()
    stir        = models.IntegerField()
```

forms.py

```
class ActiveForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=ActiveMeas
```

html file

```
<form action="" method="post" id="activeform">
    <div id="ajaxwrapper">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p id="sendwrapper"><input type="submit" value="Start" id="idstartbut" name="_ButtonStart"/></p>
    <p id="sendwrapper"><input type="submit" value="Stop" id="idstopbut" name="_ButtonStop"/></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the view file where I never get into the *buttonstart* or *buttonstop*. Another question is how do I return data to the javascript and update it from there?

views.py

```
def active(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = ActiveForm(request.POST)
        if '_ButtonStart' in request.POST:
            print "START"
            if form.is_valid():
                response_data = {'data':request.POST}
                return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data))
            else:
                print "NOT VALID"
                response_data = {'data':request.POST}
                return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data))
        elif '_ButtonStop' in request.POST:
            print "STOP"
    else:
        form = ActiveForm()
    return render(request, 'active.html', {'index': "active",'form':form})
```

javascript

```
function ActiveInit(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(function() {
        var form = $("#activeform");
        form.submit(function(e) {
            $("#ajaxwrapper").load(
                form.attr('action') + ' #ajaxwrapper',
                form.serializeArray(),
            );
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });
    });
}
```

I'm very new to both django, ajax and jQuery. So please enlighten me if something is to be done different, and how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quiet some more searching, I found the jQuery form plugin http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/ which does exacly what I wanted.

So simply my javascript is now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#aform').ajaxForm(function(data){
        if(data){
              //Do something with the returned data
        }
    });
});
```

Which both sends the form and submit value to my view.

My view function then dumps the errors to jQuery for then to be shown if any

```
if request.POST:
    form = ActiveForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        errors=""
        if '_ButtonStart' in request.POST:
            print "START"
        elif '_ButtonStop' in request.POST:
            print "STOP"
    else:
        print "NOT VALID stop"
        errors=form.errors
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(errors))
else:
    form = ActiveForm()
    return render(request, 'active.html', {'index': "active",'form':form})
```

In javascript, the errors can then be read by:

```
var errors = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(errors.samples);     //Samples is an inputbox in my form
```

Answer (score 2):

there is nothing different to submitting form with ajax or without.

In one case browser takes care of everything and puts together query sent to server, in case of ajax, all that is done by javascript - jQuery in your case.

Look at this:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Now how about to get returned validating data back from django?

There are 2 approaches:

1) Return rendered template of a form and just replace existing from with returned form. In that case you need to render all error messages in that template.
take a look at these links:
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1094/
[How do I display the Django '__all__' form errors in the template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525905/how-do-i-display-the-django-all-form-errors-in-the-template)

2) In second case you can manually put together list of all form errors on django side. turn them into json and then write script that matches errors with elements on website and then shows them.

If you are new to jquery and django then 1) is much easyer to do that 2)

Good luck

Comment: Thank you. Well, the biggest problem right now is that I cannot check in my view which button has been pressed. Probably need to do something more in the jQuery load, but not sure about what.

Comment: Submit buttons are for submitting form. Or generally sending some kind of information to server. But you want to tie some extra information to this? In that case add 2 extra fields to your form. for that add __init__ method to your form and in that method add 2 forms.BoolenFields. One for stop and one for start. Then in javascript, based on which button was clicked, set that fields value to true, then posting the form will take care of everything.