# Django form field and JQuery client side validation

Tags: jquery, django, forms, validation

I am trying to validate the fields on the client side using JQuery validate and Django form fields. How can I pass this Django form field to JQuery?

In a template
JQuery

```
<script>
FORM_RULES = {
     '{{ form.first_name.name }}': 'required'
}
FORM_MESSAGES = {
'{{ form.first_name.name }}': 'Please e first name.'
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').validate({
    rules: FORM_RULES,
    messages: FORM_MESSAGES
  });
});
<\script>
```

form fields,

```
   <label for="id_first_name">Enter your first name</label>
   {{ form.first_name }}
   <span id="id_first_name" class="error">{{ form.first_name.errors}}
```

It doesn't work. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Post the html output as well.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this link can be helpful for you.

http://streamhacker.com/2010/03/08/jquery-validation-django-forms/

Otherwise Ajax based validation could have been other option.

[Django form validation using Ajax and multiple submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842747/django-form-validation-using-ajax-and-multiple-submit)

If Still causing problems.Kindly comment. cheers :-)

Comment: Do this------------Right click on browser window --->Inspect element->console.    See if it is showing any wierd messages or errors. Try to post them in comment or if possible just copy paste your html as asked in previous comment as well.

Comment: Yes, I replaced the form.field tag with the normal html name, so it worked.